# Deselect a pytest test in the test itself

Tags: pytest

I already know that we can use marks and then call pytest with -m to execute only certain tests

my question is: is there a way to mark a test so that that test is not executed without adding any -m when calling pytest?

EDIT:

I am thinking something like:

1. mark the test with a special (I don't know if that exists, that is why this question) mark the test `thespecialtest.py` as
   `@pytest.mark.notselect`

then running the tests like always: `pytest` will exclude that test.

2. If I want to run that test specifically I can do explicitly `pytest thescpecialtest.py`

I know that the best and easiest way would be just to use -m in calling pytest but I want to ask if there is an option where this would not be necessary

Comment: You can use the `@unittest.skip` annotation to ignore a test, but I don't think you can re-enable it without removing the annotation again.

Comment: So you want to ignore the test by default when running `pytest`? You can put the command line args into `pytest.ini` so you don't have to enter them each time, so running `pytest` with `addopts = --ignore test_module.py` becomes the same as invoking `pytest --ignore test_module.py` explicitly.

Comment: You can also exclude tests programmatically, but this is an overkill here IMO.

Answer (score 0):

-m option is probably the most comfortable to use for this use case.

However, you can choose what tests to run based on names with [-k option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#using-k-expr-to-select-tests-based-on-their-name), which is basically the same as -m option, but you select test cases based on their names, rather than marks.

Another option is you can change [test discovery process](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html), so you can for example tell pytest to collect and execute only functions that comply to a certain name patters, e.g. you add to your `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
python_functions = *_check
```

which tells pytest to collect and execute only functions that comply to this glob pattern. You can do this with classes and files as well.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to mark the test so that I don't have to modify the way I run the pytest (without using -m or -k). I know it is a bit of a stretch but I want to discard if there is no way to do that

Comment: At least I don't know about any other way than using command-line options or changing test discovery process. I also briefly looked into pytest docs, and I don't see anything else closer to what you're looking for. Perhaps someone else will come and find a better way for you.